# How to troubleshoot System.OutOfMemoryException while trying to install Fedora on laptop?

Tags: linux, powershell, installation, operating-system, fedora

I am installing Fedora Live Workstation on my laptop and I got stuck on the step ["3.3.1. Verifying checksums on Windows systems" item "5.Calculate the downloaded image's checksum. This will take a while!"](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/23/html/Installation_Guide/sect-verifying-images.html). The Windows PowerShell keeps throwing the following exception:

```
$download_checksum = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($sha256.ComputeHash([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("$PWD\$image"))).ToLower() -replace '-', ''
Eccezione durante la chiamata di "ReadAllBytes" con "1" argomento/i: "Generata eccezione di tipo 'System.OutOfMemoryException'." 
(Exception during the call of "ReadAllBytes" with "1" argument:"Generate exception type 'System.OutOfMemoryException'.")
In riga:1 car:104 (In line:1 char:104)
+ $download_checksum = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($sha256.ComputeHash([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes <<<< ("$PWD\$image"))).ToLower() -replace '-', ''
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

I am not proficient on Windows Powershell and not a very skilled programmer but in order to solve this problem I have raised some hypothesis. Please correct me if they're not relevant.

1. If the cause of this exception is the hardware (e.g. insufficient RAM memory to process the computation), are there any workarounds like splitting the computation into smaller steps allowing the computer to handle smaller chuncks of information?
2. Is it possible that the interpreter have gone overflow because of compilation mistakes while tweaking the instructions into the powershell?

---

Some important information might be:

- OS: Windows 7 Professional SP 1   Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU
  M 520 @ 2.40GHz 2.40GHz
- RAM: 3,00GB (2,86GB Useful)
- OS Type: 64bit
- HD Available: 94,6 GB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't read the entire file into memory. Do this instead:

```
$filename = Join-Path $PWD $image

$sha256 = New-Object Security.Cryptography.SHA256CryptoServiceProvider

$stream = (Get-Item $filename).OpenRead()
$hash = $sha256.ComputeHash($stream)
$stream.Close()

$download_checksum = [BitConverter]::ToString($hash).ToLower() -replace '-'
```

Comment: Thank you @Ansgar Wiechers, your suggestion worked out even though I figured that my file didn't pass the Checksum test.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like MS doesn't have a good memory management. The checksum verification is optional and the windows-way is way too complicated.

> If the cause of this exception is the hardware (e.g., insufficient RAM memory to process the computation), are there any workarounds like splitting the computation into smaller steps allowing the computer to handle smaller chuncks of information?

Don't know about any reasonable way.

I would solve this by burning the iso (believing there are no errors), booting into live-CD and doing checksum under Linux, which is way too easier.

Comment: Thanks, Jakuje! unfortunately I don't have a CD right now. I'll try your solution as soon as I can.

Comment: Or to put it on flash drive. It does not have to be CD. Or do whatever you planed to do with it in the first place.

Comment: If people insist on reading entire ISO images into memory that's hardly Microsoft's fault. The Fedora people apparently just don't know PowerShell very well.

Comment: Thanks, @Jakuje. Unfortunately my file didn't pass the checksum test.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Thanks for your solution. I've filed a [bug against the documentation](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/23/html/Installation_Guide/sect-verifying-images.html) pointing back to this question. (It's unfortunately a little arcane to get changes into the docs directly, but the docs team is great about responding to filed tickets.

Comment: @matdm seems like I was [faster](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1303424). Sorry that I didn't mention that I did so. Feel free to join the [bugs together](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1303989).

Comment: I had filed a bug myself ([#1303428](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1303428)), which has been marked as a duplicate of [#1175759](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1175759).

Comment: Awesome. :) Thanks everyone. Also worth noting that we're looking at changing our primary download to be a multi-platform USB creator application rather than the ISOs directly, and this should include verification, hopefully making this moot for most users.